# HTML div background by CSS not always working

Tags: html, css, image, background

I've got this snippet in my `<body>`:

```
<div class="hero">
...content...
</div>
```

Nothing too special I figured. My CSS contains a "background:" in the class for the image. The CSS looks like this and it works:

```
.hero {
  position: relative;
  background: url(http://www.example.com/img/background.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ef4d39;
  padding-top: 110px;
  min-height: 500px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

But when I change it to this (one of the many ways I tried to make it local instead of absolute) it doesn't work:

```
background: url("img/background.png") no-repeat center center fixed; //Should be the proper way
background: url('img/background.png') no-repeat center center fixed; //Found it with single quotes in tutorials as well
background: url(img/background.png) no-repeat center center fixed; //No quotes since the original snippet doesn't contain quotes
background-image: url("img/background.png") no-repeat center center fixed; //Found this tag in tutorials as well
```

I'm quite flabbergasted (but I'm not that quite of a programmer as well) but I can't figure out why the original line works and the other lines I tried do not work. This was tested offline. Can anyone explain why and how I can make it work for relative images?

Edit:
Thanks to the comment of DBS I figured what was wrong, the right context should be:

```
background: url("../img/background.png") no-repeat center center fixed;
```

The .css is in a subfolder "css" and the image is in a subfolder "img". Thanks for the help you guys!

Comment: Sorry for the obvious question, but are you sure the resource is being loaded, ie the image is in the correct place and the url is to the correct location?

Comment: The local url of the image might be wrong. Can you please let us know the directory structure of your project ? Like where's the `img` folder and the `css` file ?

Comment: Remember, the relative path is relative to the CSS file, not the HTML file. It may not be your problem, but it's one of the most common issues in this situation.

Comment: The last line is wrong. `background-image` can only refer to the image, not the positioning. Also, you don't _really_ have `//` comments in your CSS, right?

Comment: I've tried your example local and it works, as the others already mentioned, is the url of your image right?

Comment: I think the OP _provided_ the required minimalexample, closing this question would be maybe not a really perfect decision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you no put these images at the same site, maybe they there are but you can't see them.

You must attach this images on html (look for img tag), inside your div, then you can put that in css for each one in addition would be nice set this orders apart. Try that:

```
background-repeat:no-repeat; 
background-attachment:fixed; 
background-position:center;
```

Surely you was seeing just one, but there was all of them use your browser debugger to check if they are there (press f12).

I hope I have helped.